# Best way to parse json in Ruby for the format given

Tags: ruby

For my rails app, SQL query result is received in the below format.

```
   @data= JSON.parse(request,symbolize_names: true)[:data] 
#  @data sample

 [{"time":"2017-11-14","A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0},
  {"time":"2017-11-15","A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0},
  {"time":"2017-11-16","A":2,"B":1,"C":1,"D":0,"E":1},
  {"time":"2017-11-17","A":0,"B":0,"C":1,"D":0,"E":1},
  {"time":"2017-11-20","A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0},
  {"time":"2017-11-21","A":6,"B":17,"C":0,"D":0,"E":1}]
```

But I want the data in the format

```
  [{"name":"A","data":{"2017-11-16":2,"2017-11-21":6}},
  {"name":"B","data":{"2017-11-16":1,"2017-11-21":17}},
  {"name":"C","data":{"2017-11-16":1,"2017-11-17":1}},
  {"name":"D","data":{}},
  {"name":"E","data":{"2017-11-16":1,"2017-11-17":1,"2017-11-21":1}}]
```

What is the best way to parse this in Ruby? 
I tried using @data.each method, but it is lengthy.

I am totally new to Ruby. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly specific question, but kinda an interesting problem so I took a stab at it. If this is coming from a SQL database I feel like the better solution would be to have SQL format the data for you as opposed to transforming it in ruby.

```
@data = JSON.parse(request,symbolize_names: true)[:data]

intermediate = {}
@data.each do |row|
  time = row.delete(:time)
  row.each do |key, val|
    intermediate[key] ||= {data: {}}
    intermediate[key][:data][time] = val if val > 0
  end
end

transformed = []
intermediate.each do |key, val|
  transformed << {name: key.to_s, data: val}
end
```

At the end of this `transformed` will contain the transformed data. Horrible variable names, and I hate having to do this in two passes. But got something working and figured I would share in case it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with csexton that it looks like a better query to source the data would be the ultimate solution here.

Anyway, here's a solution that's similar to csexton's but uses nested default Hash procs to simplify some of the operations:

```
def pivot(arr, column)
  results = Hash.new do |hash, key|
    hash[key] = Hash.new(0)
  end

  arr.each do |hash|
    data = hash.dup
    pivot = data.delete(column)

    data.each_pair do |name, value|
      results[name][pivot] += value
    end
  end

  results.map { |name, data| {
    name: name.to_s,
    data: data.delete_if { |_, sum| sum.zero? }
  }}
end

pivot(@data, :time) # => [{:name=>"A", :data=>{"2017-11-16"=>2, "2017-11-21"=>6}}, ..
```

Here's a more "Ruby-ish" (depending on who you ask) solution:

```
def pivot(arr, column)
  arr
    .flat_map do |hash|
      hash
        .to_a
        .delete_if { |key, _| key == column }
        .map! { |data| data << hash[column] }
    end
    .group_by(&:shift)
    .map { |name, outer| {
      name: name.to_s,
      data: outer
        .group_by(&:last)
        .transform_values! { |inner| inner.sum(&:first) }
        .delete_if { |_, sum| sum.zero? }
    }}
end

pivot(@data, :time) # => [{:name=>"A", :data=>{"2017-11-16"=>2, "2017-11-21"=>6}}, ..
```

Quite frankly, I find it pretty unreadable and I wouldn't want to support it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{"time":"2017-11-14","A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0},
       {"time":"2017-11-15","A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0},
       {"time":"2017-11-16","A":2,"B":1,"C":1,"D":0,"E":1},
       {"time":"2017-11-17","A":0,"B":0,"C":1,"D":0,"E":1},
       {"time":"2017-11-20","A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0},
       {"time":"2017-11-21","A":6,"B":17,"C":0,"D":0,"E":1}]

(arr.first.keys - [:time]).map do |key|
   { name: key.to_s,
     data: arr.select { |h| h[key] > 0 }.
               each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g.update(h[:time]=>h[key]) } }
end
  #=> [{:name=>"A", :data=>{"2017-11-16"=>2, "2017-11-21"=>6}},
  #    {:name=>"B", :data=>{"2017-11-16"=>1, "2017-11-21"=>17}},
  #    {:name=>"C", :data=>{"2017-11-16"=>1, "2017-11-17"=>1}},
  #    {:name=>"D", :data=>{}},
  #    {:name=>"E", :data=>{"2017-11-16"=>1, "2017-11-17"=>1, "2017-11-21"=>1}}]
```

Note that

```
arr.first.keys - [:time]
  #=> [:A, :B, :C, :D, :E]
```